# Reputation sorting on the Users page

Tags: discussion, reputation, search, sorting

How does StackOverflow prepares a reputation sorted list of users on the Users page where users are always sorted by their scores & may be filtered as well by the typing in a part of the name ? Is that done for each reuqest or is it cached ? Are these reputation counters stored in lucene ?

On top of what technologies, is it implemented ?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network